# Pattern matching logs in ubuntu

Tags: unix, ubuntu, grep, pattern-matching

myfile.log contains things like:

```
----- 12:08:12 (123.123.123.123) --------------------------------
Some code here...
This section has no specified length...
-----------------------------------------------------------------


----- 12:10:15 (254.14.187.123) --------------------------------
Some code here...
This section has no specified length...
It could be 3 lines, or 4 lines, or 20 lines. 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to use something like grep to pull out every block that contains the IP address 123.123.123.123. For example, the following would be returned:

```
----- 12:08:12 (123.123.123.123) --------------------------------
Some code here...
This section has no specified length...
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Edit:** 
Thanks for the answers so far, I forgot to mention that I need it to stream the output in the same way `tail` would.

Comment: is it safe to say a section from the log file is delimited by ... IP address ....  blank-line? or may there be blank lines in a section? you should be able to take any working solution and chain it togehter like `tail -f logfile | sed ...` . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something similar to:

```
sed -n '/^-----.*(123\.123\.123\.123) ---/,/^------/p' file.log
```

It first matches a line, starting with 5 hyphens, then contains a number of arbitrary characters, then the IP address enclosed in parentheses, followed by some hyphens. Then it matches all lines until it encounters a line that starts with 5 hyphens. You could use `/^-\{5,\}$/` to specify a line that contains hyphens only (at least 5).

Regarding the edit on your question: with streaming I assume you mean `tail -f`? Simply pipe its output into sed:

```
tail -f file.log | sed -n '/^-----.*(123\.123\.123\.123) ---/,/^------/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

does this give you what you want?

```
sed -n '/123\.123\.123\.123/,/^-*$/{p}' yourFile
```

Comment: You might want to make the beginning regex stricter, in case some data sections might also happen to match the IP address. `sed -n /^----- [0-9:]* \(123\.123\.123\.123\) ---*$/,/^-----*$/p' yourfile`.  (Note also the absence of brackets around the `p` command, they are optional when you only have one action.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -A <NUM>`. This will print `NUM` lines of trailing context after matching lines

Comment: Thanks, this won't work as the amount of lines between the IP address and the `----------------------------------` can vary.